# Writing a C program to call another program without using any built-in libraries

Tags: c, embedded, bootloader

I am trying to write a simple 'go-command' for boot-loader that takes me to specific address in RAM say 0x18000000 and it should execute a program that blinks led. I have two .c files say led.c and go.c in which led.c blinks two leds. But I am wondering and don't know that how can I pass a control/invoke its main() to this go.c file to go to that address and start blinking leds? But it should be done without including other header files, libraries, etc. Kindly help me!! Thanks in advance. Below code is for led.c

```
void delay ()
{
    volatile int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {}

}
int main(void)
{
    *led0=0;
    *led1=0;
    while(1)
    {
        *led0=1;
        delay();
        *led0=0;
        *led1=1;
        delay();
        *led1=0;
    }
}
```

In my go.c file I want to pass a control to invoke this led.c main() func

Comment: If you're programming in C, why did you add the C++ tag? Only add the tag of the language you're actually programming in. You could also expand on the environment, like if you're doing this for a PC platform or an embedded system. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I m sorry! If you be so kind please post the solution

Comment: VTC as too broad: This heavily depends on your environment. You could for example define your own entry point, use a linker script that puts this at the very start of your binary and jump there, either using assembly code or the start address cast to a function pointer -- but no good answer is possible without more details.

Comment: What sort of computer are you programming this on? A normal operating system just won't let you do it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I have already pointed in linker script 'link.ld' to its starting address i.e. 0x18000000 is defind as entry point. What else do u need in details? I can provide you.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I am programming in Linux particularly in C language

Comment: @kni but this starting point probably isn't `main()`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen This starting point 0x18000000 is the starting address of RAM.

Comment: @kni yes and you can jump there e.g. using the `gcc` specific syntax presented in the answer, just replace with your address. I just doubt that it's the code in `main()` that ends up at this address.

Comment: @FelixPalmen 0x18000000 is the starting address of DDR3 RAM. I just want to invoke in go.c from this address

Comment: On a bare metal embedded system this wouldn't be any problem. You could just set a function pointer of the correct format to point at a fixed address, then call that function. This is often how bootloaders etc that are provided as raw assembler are called. From a hosted system such as Linux, it wouldn't work though, since processes are not allowed to write into each other address spaces.

Comment: @FelixPalmen  Another thing i forgot to mention is that I am making .elf to .srec and loading this .srec to RAM. Starting form this address 0x1800000 it has some 4bytes of data that is generated by elf to .srec to be downloaded onto memory

Comment: @Lundin How? can you explain by example? I didn't quite get that! May be i m so much confused now!!

Comment: main is not an entry point generally are you wanting to enter at main or wanting to run the code you downloaded via elf/srec/binary?

Comment: @old_timer I want to run the code downloaded .srec file to my target which is MAX10 FPGA

Comment: @kni :  You are making increasingly less sense; An FPGA is not a _target_ for software.  You might implement a soft-core processor on the FPGA and run software on that.  You said that you were running Linux, but if that were the case you would not need to do this.  Did you mean Linux was your development host environment rather than your target environment; because that is not what you were asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC has an extension that allows jumping to an arbitrary address, so if you know the address of your led.c main you could do something like that:

```
void *func_ptr = (void *)0x1234567;  // address of your led routine
goto *func_ptr;
```

However, you probably don't have the address of the led routine and it is not a very safe operation. Jumping to some unknown address will probably result in a crash!!

Comment: In linker script I have given starting address 0x18000000

Comment: Then how should I do it?

Comment: If you are sure that 0x18000000 is the RAM address of your routine just copy this address in the first line of code, in place of 0x1234567

Comment: I have done same as u have told me i.e. replace 0x1234567 with 0x18000000 but nothing happend!! :( :( Any other suggestions?

Comment: Isn't that interpreted as an address in _this_ process's virtual memory space?

Comment: I am using your code for passing a control to led.c and led.c code is mentioned in my question. Another thing i forgot to mention is that I am making .elf to .srec and loading this .srec to RAM. Starting form this address 0x1800000 it has some 4bytes of data that is generated by elf to .srec to be downloaded onto memory

Comment: @kni: Operating systems are abstractions. If you want to program like this I suggest bare-metal.

Comment: @kni: I was in fact skeptical in my answer. From what you are saying it seems that you are looking for a bootloader

Comment: @SimoneCifani exactly!!! Now u got it!! I am trying to implement 'go' command of bootloader!! e.g go 0x18000000 in the ram and it should blink LEDs since I have successfully downloaded .srec file

Comment: @SimoneCifani I have go.c in which I have different commands in main() and I have a function to go to a specific address goto_addr() in which I wrote your routine. But writing your code it is coming in the main() of go.c rather than led.c

Comment: @kni: you mean that my code makes the program jump to a different point or it doesn't jump at all?

Comment: @Simone Cifani It jumps to a main() in go.c rather than main () of led.c. I mean functionally it is working right. But what i need is that in go.c i want to invoke main() of led.c

Comment: @kni: you are probably passing a wrong address. I found [this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87930/avr-and-bootloaders-where-to-begin) on writing an AVR bootloader and the code is pretty the same

Comment: is this an AVR or do we know what target?

Comment: main() is not an entry point, you want to branch to the entry point which then calls main, if your new program is downloaded to 0x18000000 then use the code provided in this answer with that address.  depending on the architecture it may or may not work (may crash with an ARM cortex-m for example) but that is solve able, you are not the first person to create a bootloader.

Comment: @old_timer The target is not AVR, it is MAX10 FPGA. Yes, my code is downloaded at 0x18000000 and when I use above mentioned code it takes me to main() of go.c rather than executing led.c program which I actually want to blink LEDS at a specified address. If you have any other link or any other suggestion please tell me? I have searched a lot but other than this solution, I found nothing. I have really searched a lot!!

Comment: @kni: have you read [this document](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/an/an730.pdf) from Altera?

Comment: @SimoneCifani I already studied this. But I am using RISC-V soft core processor not the oneprovided by them which is NIOS-2

Comment: @kni: I am not an expert with FPGA, sorry :-(

Comment: main is not an entry point...the bootstrap before main is an entry point from the nature of your question I dont think you are ready to be trying to branch directly into main yet (if ever since it is the wrong thing to do)...

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot you have omitted that is likely to be relevant, but taken at face value, you simply declare a function pointer, initialised with the absolute address and invoke the function through that pointer.

However it may not be that simple since the called program will use the C run-time environment of the calling program; any global static objects will not be initialised  - you need to call the program entry point (which is not`main()`) to establish the run-time environment expected by the program.  In simple case it may work or appear to work to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

So I have an sifive riscv board, going to be a little different than yours but here is an led blinker program (compiled version):

```
Disassembly of section .text:

80001000 <_start>:
80001000:   80004137            lui x2,0x80004
80001004:   016000ef            jal x1,8000101a <notmain>
80001008:   9002                    ebreak
8000100a:   a001                    j   8000100a <_start+0xa>

8000100c <dummy>:
8000100c:   8082                    ret

8000100e <PUT32>:
8000100e:   00b52023            sw  x11,0(x10)
80001012:   8082                    ret

80001014 <GET32>:
80001014:   00052503            lw  x10,0(x10)
80001018:   8082                    ret

8000101a <notmain>:
8000101a:   1101                    addi    x2,x2,-32
8000101c:   c84a                    sw  x18,16(x2)
8000101e:   10012937            lui x18,0x10012
80001022:   00890513            addi    x10,x18,8 # 10012008 <_start-0x6ffeeff8>
80001026:   006805b7            lui x11,0x680
8000102a:   ce06                    sw  x1,28(x2)
8000102c:   ca26                    sw  x9,20(x2)
8000102e:   c64e                    sw  x19,12(x2)
80001030:   cc22                    sw  x8,24(x2)
80001032:   3ff1                    jal 8000100e <PUT32>
80001034:   00c90513            addi    x10,x18,12
80001038:   006805b7            lui x11,0x680
8000103c:   3fc9                    jal 8000100e <PUT32>
8000103e:   04090513            addi    x10,x18,64
80001042:   4581                    li  x11,0
80001044:   001e84b7            lui x9,0x1e8
80001048:   37d9                    jal 8000100e <PUT32>
8000104a:   006809b7            lui x19,0x680
8000104e:   0931                    addi    x18,x18,12
80001050:   48048493            addi    x9,x9,1152 # 1e8480 <_start-0x7fe18b80>
80001054:   85ce                    mv  x11,x19
80001056:   854a                    mv  x10,x18
80001058:   3f5d                    jal 8000100e <PUT32>
8000105a:   4401                    li  x8,0
8000105c:   8522                    mv  x10,x8
8000105e:   0405                    addi    x8,x8,1
80001060:   3775                    jal 8000100c <dummy>
80001062:   fe941de3            bne x8,x9,8000105c <notmain+0x42>
80001066:   4581                    li  x11,0
80001068:   854a                    mv  x10,x18
8000106a:   3755                    jal 8000100e <PUT32>
8000106c:   4401                    li  x8,0
8000106e:   8522                    mv  x10,x8
80001070:   0405                    addi    x8,x8,1
80001072:   3f69                    jal 8000100c <dummy>
80001074:   fe941de3            bne x8,x9,8000106e <notmain+0x54>
80001078:   bff1                    j   80001054 <notmain+0x3a>
```

the disassembly spacing is a little broken but thats okay.  The entry point IS NOT AT MAIN() for a normal program it is at the start in this case 0x80001000 NOT 0x8000101A which I intentionally name something other than main on purpose (for bare metal)...There should be no reason for you to to enter at main you should enter at the entry point...I will let you simply fail if you continue to try otherwise, you are on your own with that.

So this represents an srec of the above.

```
S00F00006E6F746D61696E2E737265631F
S3158000100037410080EF006001029001A0828023209A
S31580001010B500828003250500828001114AC83729E0
S31580001020011013058900B705680006CE26CA4EC68C
S3158000103022CCF13F1305C900B7056800C93F1305E7
S3158000104009048145B7841E00D937B709680031097C
S3158000105093840448CE854A855D3F014422850504F4
S315800010607537E31D94FE81454A85553701442285AF
S30F800010700504693FE31D94FEF1BFFD
S705800010006A
```

I/we assume you are not actually downloading that to ram as is, that will never execute, your bootloader has to parse that then write the program to ram, two different things (the program itself and a file format that describes that program).

Assuming you get to that point, all you need to do is branch to 0x80001000 in my case or 0x18000000 in yours.

so taking the answer already provided to you you can do this to launch the downloaded program

```
void hop ( void )
{
    void *func_ptr = (void *)0x80001000;
    goto *func_ptr;
}
```

which results in

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <hop>:
   0:   800017b7            lui x15,0x80001
   4:   8782                    jr  x15
```

Or my personal preference would be:

```
.globl HOP
HOP:
    jr x11
```

which from C I would call with

```
HOP(0x80001000);
```

that way I can insure the instruction I wanted is used. YMMV.

How far along this path have you gotten?  Are you stuck at the last step?  Simone provided an answer that should work just fine, there are other variations on that theme from C that you can use, but that one already appears to work.

Comment: so if this is your problem upvote/accept Simone's answer

Comment: Note they give you the entry point if you built your binary right S705800010006A

Comment: this is as simple as it gets, if your prior program has interrupts enabled for peripherals or the cache enabled, etc.  Then you need to clean up all of those things before you can launch the next program...

Comment: Yup. I am parsing and then writing program to RAM.