# Accessing pointer variable of one .c file in another standalone .c file without using .h file

Tags: c, embedded, bootloader, bare-metal

Firstly the scenario, my host environment is Linux, target is MAX10 FPGA and running RISCV soft processor and writing software for that. I am writing a simple bootloader in which I have one file main.c where all the functions are defined and another file led.c which is a standalone application. Now I want to go from main.c to led.c using some address say 0x08000000. This is achieved by using following code!

```
void (*func_ptr)(void);
func_ptr = (void*)0x08000000;  //starting address of led routine                       
func_ptr();
```

In this main.c I have addresses of two LEDS which are declared at the top like this

```
volatile int* ledr = (volatile int*)(0x10000010);
volatile int* ledg = (volatile int*)(0x10000020);
```

I am converting this led.c to .srec format and downloading it to FPGA RAM after parsing.

Till here it is working perfectly!! It is going to this application. But unfortunately in led.c, it doesn't know the address of leds where i have written blinking leds program. Although delay() function is working properly but as far as I can figure out till here is that led.c doesn't know addresses so that is why I am unable to see blinking leds on my FPGA. Blinking LEDS program is below which is complete led.c file

```
volatile int* led0 = (volatile int*)(0x10000010);
volatile int* led1 = (volatile int*)(0x10000020);

static void delay ()
{
  volatile int i;
  for(i=0; i<1000000; i++)
  {
  }

}

int main(void)
{

  *led0=0;
  *led1=0;
  while(1)
  { 

     *led0=1;
     delay();
     *led0=0;
     *led1=1;
     delay();
     *led1=0;
  }

}
```

Anyone here who can give me idea that what is wrong here and what should I do? Your help will be appreciated!!

P.S. When it goes in this application it remains in while loop and that means it is working properly, but not blinking leds. I have double checked this thing!

Comment: Following this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412356/writing-a-c-program-to-call-another-program-without-using-any-built-in-libraries).

Comment: Please explain the difference between this question and the one found by WeatherVane. Without help, I do not see the difference. Then explain, based on the difference, why the answer you accepted there is not helpful here.

Comment: @Yunnosch : The previous question was about passing control to a particular memory address. This question is pretty much about why his LED's aren't flashing despite the fact he thinks the code to do it is running.

Comment: do you have some working led blinking code?  what bit/pin are the leds on in that register, and what is that/those registers?

Comment: what/whose led peripheral are you using?  what do those registers do?

Comment: @Yunnosch I accepted that answer because it solved my problem and it took me to other application .i.e led.c. Secondly, I solved the problem and now led's are blinking!! For some bad reason(explanation is long), bootloader was going to its reset position!

Comment: Voting to close as you say you are asking a question about "Accessing pointer variable of one .c file in another standalone .c file without using .h file" but then instead of trying to do that, you simply define the pointers in each file, and wonder about why these now *independent* programs aren't working.

Answer (score -1):

no you will need a third party file either a peripheral "driver" file that both programs use, or a header file.  I assume by now you understand that main.c and led.c are not your whole program, there is a bootstrap at a minimum if not other code that the toolchain adds to make a complete program.

Either use a third common file or provide the same code/information both files.  this has nothing to do with arm or fpgas, elemetary C programming.